# Calculate the total number of days from month and year in java

Tags: java, calendar, days, monthcalendar, leap-year

I need some logic to calculate the total number of days. For example
If i enter 3 means ,it will calculate total number of days from current month to next two months.

Same as Year. If i enter 3 means it will calculate the total number of days from current year to next two year.

Total number of days = enter value * month.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. Is this is your homework I assume your teacher wants you to implement your own functions for leap-year and counting days.

If this is just for an application I would just use java 8 LocalDate:

for moths days diff:

```
    LocalDate ldStart = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ldEnd = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(2);

    long days = ldStart.until(ldEnd, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(days);
```

for years day diff:

```
    LocalDate ldStart = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ldEnd = LocalDate.now().plusYears(2);

    long days = ldStart.until(ldEnd, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: Some tags are not supported in Android.until and ChronoUnit keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The 'java.util.Calendar' has what you need. Create a new Calendar and save `getTime()` in a variable for comparison. Then use the `Calendar.add` method to get a date in the future - it can add 3 months if that's what you want. Call `getTime()` again. The base unit for these times is milliseconds, so you can subtract one from the other to get the number of milliseconds between the dates. Divide this by 86,400,000 (the number of milliseconds in a day) to get the number of days between your dates.